# "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded" - Video not play in Android OS 7.1.2

Tags: android, webview

I want to play video in Webview but it doesn't played in Android OS 7.1.2

```
2021-04-20 16:54:31.139 5572-5694/info.player E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(811)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
2021-04-20 16:54:31.173 5572-5572/info.player I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.", source: videourl
2021-04-20 16:54:32.148 5572-5572/info.player I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded", source: videourl
2021-04-20 16:54:32.880 5572-5673/info.player W/chromium: [WARNING:opensles_util.cc(25)] Guessing channel layout for 6 channels; speaker order may be incorrect.
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No and this is issue occur only in Android OS 7.1.2

Comment: I read it may be benign but I have a video (3D facial scan) that is not working and this error appears when the issue is present in the UI